# Synonyms & materialized view

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, synonym, multiple-users

1. I have two tables. a) student b) restricted_student.

   2. two users a) admin b) user
   3. one synonyms **stu** for both the users. in admin it refer to student but for user it refer to restricted_student.

I want to create a materialized view MV .
The code of materialized view look like

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS;
```

such that if i am connected to admin then it should refer to student and for user it should refer to restricted_student by passing the only synonyms name stu.
something like

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS E='st';
```

the result i wanted when i connected to user it should give the **restricted_student table columns**. whereas whenever i connected to admin it should give the **student table columns**.

I created all the above objects.but materialized view is not giving the expected result as i want.

Comment: What if you create two materialized views that each point to their respective tables and then an alias that points to the views?

Comment: two materialized views is ok. But how do you suggest me to write it.My the code for materialized views look like SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal view where you can union these 2 tables and filter by the user logged in. 
Also check Oracle RLS (row level security), https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28529/intro.htm

Irrespective of the application and user, you can control how the where clause should be. That way you have a much higher control over the records that is queries.

For example,

**Admin user**
select * from stu;

**Normal user**
select * from stu;

Would have completely different results, based on the predicate you set for RLS.

Comment: I don't have to select from stu.I have to get the table structure of stu based on user log in.